# What is the difference in a division by 12 and the subtraction of a n/3 by n/4

Tags: c, algorithm, cs50

I was doing a cs50 lab and I implemented the following algorithm in c.
The code must return values in int, so I declared n_initial and n_final how int.

```
while (n_final>n_initial)
    {
        n_initial += n_initial/12;
        cont++ ;
    }
```

The problem is that with a very large value it works, in these cases it does not come out of the loop while.

For instance when n_inital = 10 and n_final = 100,the program does not come out of the loop while,only when i debug the code that it works "right",since the value does not come out as expected.

```
//other algoritm which work
while (n_final>n_initial)
    {
        n_initial += (n_initial/3) - (n_initial/4);
        cont++ ;
    }
```

so i did it that other way and it worked and I wanted to know why this,with a view to mathematically they are the same thing.
//sorry for my bad english ,I'm brasilian

Comment: Do basic debugging. Step thru the code line by line in a debugger to examine the variables as it runs to help you understand for yourself what is happening (or at least get closer to it). If you need further help please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why use for() loops if there are while() loops?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. For example, you have not shown what type `n_initial` is declared as. If it is an integer type, the divisions will truncate. If it is a floating-point type, they will likely round. In both cases, the accumulating sum may differ from what you would get in real-number arithmetic, but in different ways. So providing a good answer depends on this and other information, including what behavior you observe in the two, what the initial values are, and so on.

Comment: The sentence “The problem is that with very large value works,in these cases it does not come out of the loop while” is unclear. Are you saying the code works (in the way you desire) for large values but does not exit the loop otherwise (for small values)? Or are you saying it does not exit the loop for large values? Show examples with specific initial values of `n_final` and `n_initial` and state the behavior you observe in these examples.

Comment: ok boys ,in the next question's,i'll be clearer.

Comment: Please update this question or delete it. Stack Overflow is not a personal training service. A principal goal is to create a durable repository of questions and answers for everybody to learn from. If you leave a question unclear, it is not serving its purpose.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil now the question is better?

Comment: There is enough there to understand it now and to reproduce the problem, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `n_initial/12`.

Comment: With `n_initial=10`, the exact division n_initial/12 is less than 1, and the integer division `n_initial/12` is 0. So, `n_initial += n_initial / 12;` becomes `n_initial += 0;`, and the loop is an infinite loop. You could solve it by forcing an increment of at least 1: `n_initial += (n_initial >= 12) ? (n_initial / 12) : 1;`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `n_initial` is an integer, the result of each division will round down to the next integer.  So, for example, the result for an initial value of 33 would be:

n_initial += n_initial/12;

```
—> 33 + 2 = 35
```

n_initial += (n_initial/3) - (n_initial/4);

—> 33 + 11 - 8 = 36

So while using fractional arithmetic by hand, the two would produce the same result, when using integers the do not.  Note that if floating point arithmetic were used, the values would be nearly equivalent.

Comment: Re “If working with floating point values the result would be, in theory, equal…”: Floating-point arithmetic has rounding/truncation errors very similar to integer arithmetic, just smaller when the numbers are in this range.

Comment: Thank you,now I understood,but i still don't understand why it still doesn't come out of the while loop with a value of n_intial = 100 and n_final = 1000,for example.

Comment: @Lulusi You should mention these concrete examples / tests / etc in the question. Please update it. Here, in comment section, it is hidden.

Comment: Ok i am review the question,thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

it is clear that (in mathematics):

```
(initial/3.0) - (initial/4.0) == 
   (4.0 * initial - 3.0 * initial) / 12.0 == 
   ((4.0 - 3.0) * initial) / 12.0 ==
   (1.0 * initial) / 12.0 == 
   initial / 12.0
```

so they should be equal (as real values)... but as you are using integers (and integer division), they are not.  Integer division loses precision based on rounding erros, so the second expression gives you numbers less rounded down (as the denominators are smaller).

In the case you expose, if you divide `10` by `12` you get `0` as quotient (there's no `0.83333333333` integer number, you lose the full 10 numbers in the remainder, as the denominator is larger than the numerator), and then you end adding `0` to `initial` and this makes the loop to run forever.

When you do the second expresion, you have: `(10*4)/3 - (10*3)/4 == 40 / 3 - 30 / 4 == 13 - 7 == 6` (you lose the remainder, `40 % 3 == 1`, in the first operand, and `30 % 4 == 2` in the second) and this time you end adding a value of `6`, this makes the loop to end.

You have been operating real number algebra with integer numbers, thinking that they are real valued ones.... and so, the two expressions you wrote above are not equivalent.  You could solve your problem by introducing some floating point literals and forcing operations to be done as floating point numbers (but anyway, if you force finally your numbers to be integers, you can be again in the same problem).  As in

```
float initial;

initial += initial / 12.0; /* 0.83333333 */
initial += initial / 3.0 - initial / 4.0; /* 0.8333333 */
```

will give you the same exact (well, quasi exact) result.